# Unions confusion with sizeof

Tags: c++

I have the following union :

```
union Variant{
    char txt[10];
    double floating_point;
};
```

The confusion comes when I try to print `sizeof(Variant)` , **which outputs 16 bytes.**

Why doesn't it output 10 bytes instead of 16 ? if union takes up as much memory as its largest member, it should do `max(sizeof(char[10]), sizeof(double))` no ?

Where does the 6 bytes comes from anyway, if in my system a `double` takes 8 bytes ?

Comment: There is alignment too in play.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the [alignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Alignment) on the 8 bytes boundary, since the size of the [union](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/union)'s largest member `double` is probably `8` bytes on your machine. If you had an `int` instead of `double`, the size would probably be `12`.

The size of your `char` array is `10` bytes, because it has ten elements. Which is greater than your largest member `double` size, which is `8`. So, the next possible alignment is `2 * 8` which is `16`.

If your array had 8 elements or less, the size of the union would be `8`, etc.

Comment: What is this alignment ? It's not bits it's bytes, why would it align itself ?

Comment: [Alignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Alignment)

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't it output 10 bytes instead of 16 ? if union takes up as much mamory as its largest member, it should do max(sizeof(char[10]), sizeof(double)) no ?

The size of a structure or a class is a multiple of the alignment of a member with the largest [alignment requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Alignment). Here, that member is `double`, whose alignment is 8, i.e. `alignof(double) == 8` and `alignof(Variant) == alignof(double)`.

Comment: then it should output 8 instead of 16 no ?

Comment: @Wahalez Why would it output 8? The multiple here is 2.

Comment: Then there wouldn't be enough space for the array, so it rounds up to the next multiple of 8.